# Error building empty website in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, build, web

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 and whenever I create a new ASP.NET empty website and build it for the first time compilation is successful but I get a server error when accessing the site of "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

If I then go back and build the website again I get a single error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" but no line number.

This error occurs whichever framework I am targeting and whether I am using C# or VB.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
Richard.

Comment: please show the markup and any code you placed inside the default page which you have set as the Start Page

Comment: I get this error before I have added any markup or code.

Comment: Is this a web site (`File -> New -> Website -> ASP.NET Empty Web Site`) or a web application (`File -> New -> Project -> Web -> ASP.NET Empty Web Application`)? I've just tried both in VS2012.3, and couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: It is a web site rather than a web application.

Comment: @RichardK9: Do you have any files other than `web.config` in the site? Can you post the content of the `web.config` file?

Comment: There are no other files. The blank website menu options just creates the following web.config:<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>

Comment: @RichardK9: And you get the "could not load assembly" error when you hit F5 in VS2012? If so, it sounds like it could be a problem with your machine-level config files.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I have been suspecting that it is something specifically to do with my machine but I have no idea what or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly  AjaxControl Toolkit is the issue.

Depending on your Framework version( 4.5, 4.0, 3.5 ),, install the correct version of AjaxControl Toolkit from here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/94873.

Another solution I found is to place System.Web.Extensions.dll and System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll directly in the Bin folder of your web application.

Comment: There isn't a bin directory because this is just a website rather than a web application. The problem occurs even though I haven't created any references at all.

Comment: You need to add references. Once you build the empty website, a Bin folder will get created.